# Wiring up validation in MediatR and ASP.NET Core using autofac

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I've just started to use MediatR in an asp.net core project and am struggling to wire up validation ...

Here's my controller:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    IMediator mediator;
    public PersonController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreatePerson model)
    {
        var success = await mediator.Send(model);
        if (success)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

... and the CreatePerson command, validation (via FluentValidation) and request handler:

```
public class CreatePerson : IRequest<bool>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class CreatePersonValidator : AbstractValidator<CreatePerson>
{
    public CreatePersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.FirstName).NotEmpty().Length(1, 50);
        RuleFor(m => m.Surname).NotEmpty().Length(3, 50);
    }
}

public class CreatePersonHandler : IRequestHandler<CreatePerson, bool>
{

    public CreatePersonHandler()
    {
    }

    public bool Handle(CreatePerson message)
    {
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have this generic validation handler:

```
public class ValidatorHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> inner;
    private readonly IValidator<TRequest>[] validators;

    public ValidatorHandler(IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> inner, IValidator<TRequest>[] validators)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest message)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(message);

        var failures = validators
            .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null)
            .ToList();

        if (failures.Any())
            throw new ValidationException(failures);

        return inner.Handle(message);
    }
}
```

... but I'm struggling to wire the validation up correctly in Startup.ConfigureServices using autofac:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register<SingleInstanceFactory>(ctx =>
    {
        var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return t => c.Resolve(t);
    });
    builder.Register<MultiInstanceFactory>(ctx =>
    {
        var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return t => (IEnumerable<object>)c.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t));
    });

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CreatePersonHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

    builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(ValidatorHandler<,>), typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), "Validator").InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.Populate(services);

    var container = builder.Build();
    return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

When I run the app and POST /api/person
{
    "title": "Mr",
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "surname": ""
}

I get a 200.
CreatePersonHandler.Handle() was called but CreatePersonValidator() is never called.

Am i missing something in Startup.ConfigureServices()?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you read [the official documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators) on how to wire up decorators in Autofac.

Decorators use named services to resolve the decorated services.

For example, in your piece of code:

```cs
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(ValidatorHandler<,>),
    typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
    "Validator").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

you're instructing Autofac to use `ValidationHandler<,>` as a decorator to `IRequestHandler<,>` services that have been registered with the `Validator` name, which is probably not what you want.

Here's how you could get it working:

```cs
// Register the request handlers as named services
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CreatePersonHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
    .Named("BaseImplementation");

// Register the decorators on top of your request handlers
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(ValidatorHandler<,>),
    typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
    fromKey: "BaseImplementation").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I find specifying the name of the `fromKey` parameter helps in understanding how decorators work with Autofac.